# Ethernet device not managed

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and recently I have not been able to connect to internet using Ethernet. The network manager shows `device not managed`.
The WiFi network is working fine.

[image]

[image]

I've tried the solution from this questionn [Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761036/ubuntu-16-04-ethernet-issues)
with no use.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Output of `nmcli d`:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlp2s0  wifi      connected  eduroam    
enp8s0  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Comment: I see that "managed=true" did you change it from false to true? can you try to restart the service and see if it solve your problem: `sudo service network-manager restart` ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it from false to true. And I've tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: please add the output of `nmcli d` to your question

Comment: I've added it to the question

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The following bug in Ubuntu 16.10 might be related:  [network-manager does not manage ethernet and bluetooth interfaces when Ubuntu 16.10 is installed using chroot/netboot method](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842)

First try running the following command:

```
sudo nmcli dev set enp8s0 managed yes
```

If you get the error message:

> Error: Device 'enp8s0' not found.

Try running the command below:

```
ip link show
```

and look for a device name similar to `enp8s0` and substitute it in the original command.

---

If the that didn't solve the problem, try running the following (backup orig file, and create 0 bytes file instead)

```
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf  /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf_orig
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

> **@datka** reported a different location for The file `10-globally-managed-devices.conf` so the commands should be:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf  /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf_orig
sudo touch /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

The reboot, or restart the Network Manager service:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

or the old way:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: The second option with creating the blank file worked! Thank you!

Comment: @martin49 - happy to hear that it solve the problem :)

Comment: You saved me. The touch method worked

Comment: The second option with creating the blank file worked! Thanks very much!

Comment: The second option worked for me too. However, the file `10-globally-managed-devices.conf` was located in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d` and not in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d`.

Comment: May I additionally point to this bug [No network connectivity after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1676547)

Comment: @datka same for me, the file actually set all devices except WiFi to unmanaged, except the WiFi. This seems to be the default configuration of my Dell XPS13 developer edition, which caused a lot of headscratching for me.. thanks a lot Yaron for the fix!

Comment: @datka - thanks for the comment! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Second option worked for me too, after quite some debugging.

Comment: Please note that this also applies to 18.04:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036497/ubuntu-18-04-nmnetwork-manager-is-not-able-to-manage-network-devices/1057017#1057017

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169539/568304) for an alternative to fix this, extending instead of removing the rules for globally managed devices.

Comment: On 18.04 the file needs to contain `[keyfile]\n unmanaged-devices=none`.

Comment: Second option also worked for me, not first. Thank you!

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04 the answer (first and second option) @Yaron provided didn't work. 
Same result with `[keyfile]\n unmanaged-devices=none` and `unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet`

Comment: I confirm that second option worked for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 39):

In my case the `10-globally-managed-devices.conf` just doesn't exist (from 16.04->16.10).  All that is needed is to create it:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

Followed by a restart:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I also got this problem when I upgraded to 16.10 from 16.04. This answer worked for me, but I needed to restart Network Manager as well. `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Also a problem upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04. Cmon Ubuntu do better. Network errors are the worst. Thanks for the easy fix.  Touch then [sudo service network-manager restart].

Comment: From answers on other questions, it may exist in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/` --on my machine (18.04) it appears that putting the empty one in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/` will override that, and allow NM to manage the device.

Answer (score 10):

While the advice to create an empty `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` file worked for me, I found another way to fix this.

Calling `nmcli`, I noticed that my ethernet device isn't classified as one of the types (`wifi`, `wwan`) that are excluded from the `unmanaged-devices` clause, in contrast to the WiFi device, but as `ethernet`:

```
$ sudo nmcli 
enp0s31f6: verbunden to Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1
        "Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V"
        ethernet (e1000e), 54:E1:AD:FC:E1:22, hw, mtu 1500
        ^^^^^^^^
        [...]

wlp5s0: nicht verfügbar
        "Intel Wireless 8260 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260)"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 28:C6:3F:CD:A1:9F, hw, mtu 1500
        ^^^^
        [...]
```

Adding that type to the exceptions in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` did work for me:

```
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Strangely enough, the original setting worked for me for more than 6 months, until I decided to clean out the packages installed on my system. However I can't tell if it was the device type or the file contents that have changed with that.

Comment: This seems to be a new(er) bug that (IMHO) should get reported. I noticed it on a stripped down Ubuntu 18.04 installation that had network functional before stripping it down. So I assume there is some package that masks this error in the configuration.

Comment: This resolved it for me. Thank you very much

Comment: fixed my issue with an "Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400" network card, execute "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager" to load the config changes

Answer (score 6):

Setting `unmanaged-devices=none` in `{BASE}usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` worked for me in getting NetworkManager to manage the ethernet port, though I don't know if that messes anything else up. :^)

This was for a Ubuntu 16.10 hybrid USB build.

Comment: The only combination that worked for me was creating the file in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` and then manually setting `unmanaged-devices=none` in the location you said.

Comment: Can you paste the full 10-globally-managed-devices.conf?  I'm getting a `Failed to read configuration: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf: Key file does not start with a group` error.

Comment: The contents of the file should be (on two lines): `[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=none`

Answer (score 5):

Please be mindful that you may need to change the netplan renderer to NetworkManager.

In `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`, or `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, or (in my case) `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` (it may be a different name but it should be the only file located in that directory) add `renderer: NetworkManager` after `network:`.

it should look something like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Please also be mindful that if you wish to add the exceptions tag to `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` make sure that you add a plugin tag such as `[keyfile]` to the top of the file as per what plugins you have listed in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
`[main]                                                                                                                  plugins=ifupdown,**keyfile**`

Hope I could help, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and this had me scratching my head for a while.