# Ubuntu 17.10 Server running Ubuntu Desktop. Network Manager will not detect Ethernet

Tags: server, network-manager, 17.10

I know this question has been asked several times from Ubuntu 17.04 Server and previous. The Ubuntu Desktop, once installed, will not detect and manage the Ethernet Adapter.

I have stepped thru the previously reported fix here which has not fixed this issue for a new 17.10 Server running Ubuntu Desktop (both Gnome and Budgie)
[Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)

Points to note.

1. This Ubuntu 17.10 Server is a VirtualBox VM running on a Windoze 7 Host.
2. the VM has the NIC setting on NAT. (I don't want to expose this VM on the main router DHCP scope as it's on a work machine/network)
3. the Ubuntu 17.10 server does have functioning network but just CANNOT be managed with the Ubuntu desktop Network Manager

   [image]

I'd basically like to tweak what's needed on the Ubuntu 17.10 Server so the Network Manager will detect the network connection.

config files in the Ubuntu 17.10 Server

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Whats nice is I'm able to snapshot the VM, play, and quickly revert if something is totally munched.

I'm thinking `enp0s3` needs to be listed in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Network Manager to handle networking, I suggest that you change the netplan file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Then change the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Save and close the text editor. Next:

```
sudo netplan apply
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

Comment: No reboot required. Worked perfectly