# ubuntu 18.04, nm(Network Manager) is not able to manage network devices

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am playing around with networking component of latest Ubuntu. I faced the above issue when I tried to manage networking devices with NM.

The command line output is

```
root@sankar:~# nmcli d s
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eth0    ethernet  unmanaged  --
eth1    ethernet  unmanaged  --
eth2    ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

I tried couple of solutions(comment #36 and #30) given in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 10):

I had this happen with an installation of Ubuntu Server 18.04 (Which uses netplan) and then adding a desktop window manager GUI (in our case, [xubuntu-core^](https://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/)).

No Manner of re-configuring or `nmcli` would make these devices managed.

The solutions you tried were close, we found that if you follow the answer located here:  [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)
and note that the location of the `10-globally-managed-devices.conf` is in the folder `/user/lib/`  you will be able to active those network devices by blanking the `10-globally-managed-devices.conf` file with:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf  /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf_orig
```

and

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

And restarting network-manager or rebooting.