# Ubuntu 18.04, using a USB Ethernet adapter: after updates, Network Manager says, "No suitable device found for this connection."

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb, network-manager, ethernet

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed updates a couple days ago.  Since then, I can manually start my wired (USB-ethernet adapter) connection using iproute2 commands to bring up the link and give the interface a static IP address, but when I try to use Network Manager it says, "No suitable device found for this connection."

Answer (score 2):

Researching this again today, I came across this: [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)

Which led me to editing `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` and changing this:

```
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

to this:

```
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
```

and then doing this:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and suddenly my USB ethernet connection came right up.

Comment: It might be good idea to copy the file to /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d and edit it there. It should be safer against updates