# Ubuntu 18.04, Network Manager is not able to manage network devices (still broken)

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 server and then installed ubuntu-unity-desktop, and Network Manager is hosed. This problem has been reported more than once ([Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed/882812)) and I am sure this question will be marked as a duplicate, but I have tried all the remedies and the problem has not been resolved.

I have tried:

- editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.
- editing `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`.
- an empty `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`.

What finally fixed it was editing /etc/netplan/*.yaml

@heynnema - Why was it the wrong thing to do? It seems to have worked. My /etc/interfaces files is nothing but comments. My netplan yaml is what I finally edited, and is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

lshw reports correctly ehat my only network interface is a RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Comment: If you've found the solution, then you can [post the solution itself as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). That is, you can remove the details of the solution from your question and post an answer that contains them.