# Cannot find netboot mini iso for Ubuntu Groovy 20.10

Tags: apt, iso

### Cannot find netboot mini iso for Ubuntu Groovy 20.10

For the i386 architecture, you can download it here http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

When I click on this link this installation option is displayed
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/

> [image: netinstall]

[Netbooting the server installer on amd64](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64)

[Netbooting the live server installer](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510) This is now the only option for netinstall Ubuntu Groovy 20.10 amd64?

Comment: Been the only option since 20.04.  Cannot even upgrade to 20.04 from i386 or 32 bit system.

Answer (score 3):

The Canonical decided to stop providing this image. See these topics on Ubuntu Community and LaunchPad:

- [Netbooting the live server installer](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510/90?u=norbert)
- [Installing Groovy via PXE boot](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/installing-groovy-via-pxe-boot/18494)
- [Poll about possible netboot mini.iso revival in future Ubuntu releases](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/poll-about-possible-netboot-mini-iso-revival-in-future-ubuntu-releases/19457?u=norbert)
- https://pad.lv/1884538

As the workaround use 20.04 LTS netboot mini iso from

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

and then upgrade it to *groovy* by `do-release-upgrade` after installation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mini.iso for Ubuntu 20.10. Not the same, but you can install minimal system using **debootstrap**.
To show this method, I will use Ubuntu 20.10 live iso booted from usb. In terminal:

```
sudo su -
# Install debootstrap
apt update
apt install debootstrap

# Partitioning
fdisk -l
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdaX

mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
# Install base packages
debootstrap groovy /mnt

mount /dev /mnt/dev --bind
mount /proc /mnt/proc --bind
mount /sys /mnt/sys --bind
# Go inside new system
chroot /mnt

# Install the Linux kernel and text editor
apt update
apt install linux-image-generic nano

# Check UUID and paste it into /etc/fstab
blkid | grep sdX > /etc/fstab
# Edit fstab so it looks like this:
# UUID=<your uuid> / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
nano /etc/fstab

# Install boot-loader (Legacy BIOS)
# On UEFI, change the target to i386-efi
grub-install --target i386-pc /dev/sdX
# Optionally, edit grub settings in /etc/default/grub
update-grub

# Add user
adduser <name>
usermod -aG sudo <name>
passwd <name>

# Set time and language
dpkg-reconfigure locales
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

# Set hostname
nano /etc/hostname
```

Fix NetworkManager if you install this way:
[Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed#882812)

Answer (score 1):

### Thank you so much for your response!

Read the newsletter
[Bug 1884538 Re: Removing debian-installer from groovy](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5846368.html)

Downloaded and installed [focal mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso)

```
sudo sed -i s/Prompt=lts/Prompt=normal/g /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
do-release-upgrade -d
uname -a
Linux 5.8.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:30:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And then my choice tasksel
```