# Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Ethernet not working on 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, lan

I have an Alienware laptop with the Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 LAN adapter which worked always until after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, when it stopped working completly. I'm on the newest kernel 5.8.0-53 and `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` is installed, the ethernet hardware is detected but not working.

`sudo lshw -c network` for this device shows:

```
*-network DISABLED
```

If I enter `sudo ifconfig enp61s0 up` it supposedly starts (the `DISABLED` flag vanishes) but the ethernet is still not working. The network manager GUI does not show any ethernet related options. After rebooting it is set to `DISABLED` again.

How do I get this ethernet adapter working again?

(the WLAN, also from Qualcomm Atheros, is working perfectly fine)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed/893614#893614 did the job for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it randomly by starting to looking into NetworkManager, was not actually any driver-related problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/893614/341343

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This empty file was missing for some unknown reason. I don't know why a  missing empty file with such starnge name prevents NetworkManager to work properly, however. Sounds like a bug to me.