# Network Manager fails to restart due to timeout exceeded

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager

My ubuntu 18.04 LTS was working fine. Next thing, wifi symbol disappears and it says "NetworkManager needs to be running" in settings.

So I used restart command (`sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`) and output is:

[image: Restart cmd output pic]

Then I used the below commands :

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

and

```
journalctl -xe
```

Here are the outputs for the respective commands.

[image: Systemctl status output pic]

[image: Journalctl output pic]

Please let me know what more commands I can run and see.

Sorry for the formatting and images, I'm using phone as I'm unable to access wifi on my laptop.

P.S Restarting didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, next time you can copy and paste the text output, instead of taking photo of the display.

Comment: I don't have internet on laptop, hence using my phone. Sorry.

Comment: It's okay. I understand that you can't do it for now. By the way, I probably found the answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed

Answer (score 0):

you can restore the wifi icon by typing `nm-applet`, then

```
sudo systemctl stop network-manager
sudo systemctl start network-manager
```

Comment: nm-applet says `NetworkManager is not running` and running systemctl start network-manager gives same error as my restart screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

First try to simply start that

`sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service`

if it doesn't check the configuration files.

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

---

Some people mentioned, unmanaged devices caused failure.
[Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)