# No network after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I recently upgraded my working Ubuntu 20.04 server to 22.04 and the network does not work anymore. I am desperately trying to find a solution to this.

Output of `sudo lshw -class network` :

[image: output of lshw]

Output of `ip a` :

[image: output of ip a]

The network interface shows disabled and no matter how I try to turn it back on, it does not stay on or work. I still can't use apt update as an example.

Comment: More details are needed. Post the output of that command in the body of the question. What errors are you getting?

Comment: The error that gave away this problem is the fact that "sudo apt update" outputs a temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'. I have also put pictures of the outputs of two commands. Let me know what else I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to get my network interface to be managed to activate it. I also found out that my sources.list had https in all the links instead of http.

I found the info from these two links and probably a few more, couldn't find some of them.

[unmanaged network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed/893614#893614)

[https -> http](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610959/pop-os-not-proprely-connecting-to-https-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-focal-inrel/610970#610970)

Answer (score 0):

This answer was not help full for me, so I struggled a lot with this.
I have an Ubuntu server running Nextcloud small size server.
I was started out from somewhere before version 16.04 lts before that version it run on X.10 or X.04 (X for version number)
In the past the network handler has changed.
When I upgrade (do-release-upgrade) from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS it didn't go well with the network.
After a lot of google and use of the new chatbot.

If you at this point (and before doing anything else) have network (ping your gateway) but not being able to ping ubuntu.com

You need to add your dns server to this file:

**nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail**

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

**After that you can continue to the finale solution:**

I got to this small and simple config:
The name i used for config: **/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**

```
# config start
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.22/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
         [192.168.1.1]
        search: []
  version: 2
# config end
```

just to make sure that the netplan is all working, you should do this command:

```
apt reinstall netplan.io
```

netplan.io is the packet for netplan ...

and you can remove network manager:

```
apt purge network-manager
```

and you can remove you interface config file, I renamed it to interface.old just in case ...
And remove the tail file you created before.

And now you should be able to reboot and on you go ...
That did it for me, and now I am running with the appropriated network config file for a small and simple server running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Nextcloud.